# Custom button is being executed 3-4 times on click

Tags: java, button, lwjgl

I made a simple button class (using lwjgl to render rectangle), however when i click the button, the code that's supposed to run when clicked is executed 1-5 times.

Here's method from button class:

```
public boolean clicked(float mX, float mY){
    if(mX >= x && mX <= x + width && 
            mY <= Display.getHeight() - y && mY >= Display.getHeight() - (y + height)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's the code in the class that utilizes the button class and method:

```
public void getInput(){
    if(Mouse.next()){
        if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
            if(b.clicked(Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY())){
                System.out.println("button clicked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: In most case, you'll listen for Mouse Button Up if you need to handle the click only once, cause if the user keep the click, it will call the event each tick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple: you have to us Mouse.isButtonDown is called if your mousebutton is down. So if you press your mouse for 1 second it would call this method about 50 times(determine on the tickrate of your Program). You have to use a boolean wich store the state at the last tick. This could look like this:

```
boolean prevState;
public void update(...){
    if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0) && !prevState){
        item++;
    }
    prevState = Mouse.isButtonDown(0);
}
```

If you have a question i will try to answer it :)